# Prestashop - Call static method from smarty tpl

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using prestashop 1.7 and I have a file in the override / classes that is called Cart.php that has a function similar to this, its purpose is to return an array of objects, the code could be something like this

```
<?php
```

class Cart extends CartCore
{

```
public static function getADXFromProducts($id){


    $adxProducts=array();
    return $adxProducts;
}
```

}

I have the problem from the smarty template "Tpl" where I try to make a call to the static method in this way.

By screen I don't receive any error, but if I activate xdebug in the above override file I do not see it enter the method.

```
  {assign var=bookProducts value={Cart::getADXFromProducts($cart.id)}}
```

Thanxs

Comment: it should be used `{assign var=bookProducts value=Cart::getADXFromProducts($cart.id)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, activate a debug mode in your Prestashop within your admin panel 
**Advanced Parameters -> Performance -> Debug mode**. It would help you to see any issue if you have it

At second, be sure that you put your override file in the correct path, it has to be **'override/classes/Cart.php'**

At third, remove a file **app/cache/dev/class_index.php** it will be generated automatically and all routes will be regenerated

At last, if you want to get an array as a response you need to define your variable this way

```
{assign var='bookProducts' value=Cart::getADXFromProducts($cart.id)}
```

your way `{assign var=bookProducts value={Cart::getADXFromProducts($cart.id)}}` will work only with strings or numbers

Answer (score 0):

The static functions can be called directly in the Smarty files for example:

```
{Cart::getADXFromProducts($cart.id)}
```

But this is not recommended, you should call the function in PHP class file and then use the value in Smarty.

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('bookProducts', Cart::getADXFromProducts($cart.id));
```